# Exception of type System.ArgumentException Occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#

I am getting the above error in *global.asax.cs* class, when I run my api application. Basically it is coming from the following line:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

The additional information given is:

> an item with the same key has already been added

I really dont know where to look into to resolve the issue.

Comment: Please provide the contents of the `WebApiConfig.Register` function, which you'll likely find in `App_Start\WebApiConfig.cs`.